# Java String and Mathematical Expression Evaluators

Tags: java, string, expression, evaluator

We use the Jeks parser at present to evaluate expressions.  I cannot see a way to evaluate string expressions with it - for example:

**IF( "Test 1" = "Test 2")**

Is there anything out there that can evaluate string and mathematical expressions in Java?  Preferably free or open source.

Comment: That's not remotely syntactically correct Java code. Is that intentional?

Comment: I guess it is. He's looking for a Java-Evaluator for a Non-Java-Language (string and mathematical expressions).

Comment: Take a look at JEKS: http://www.eteks.com/jeks/en/

Comment: We use Jeks...  But I cannot see how you can evaluate IF("Test 1" = "Test 2")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was a posting on the Jeks forum.  I got an answer from Manu.  I thought it was not active especially as I could not register on it - but that got sorted.

But if anyone has the same problem then the following lines of code will get it working:

```
ExpressionParser parser; // we did have = new ExpressionParser(new JeksExpressionSyntax(), null);
JeksInterpreter interpreter; //
```

And to create the interpreter:

```
interpreter = new JeksInterpreter() {

      @Override
      public Object getBinaryOperatorValue (Object binaryOperatorKey, Object param1, Object param2)
      {
        // Only functions may take a cell set as parameter
        if ( param1 instanceof JeksCellSet || param2 instanceof JeksCellSet)
          throw new IllegalArgumentException ();
        // Enabled comparison between any type supported by Jeks
        else if (binaryOperatorKey.equals (JeksExpressionSyntax.OPERATOR_EQUAL))
          return param1 != null && param1.equals (param2)
                   ? Boolean.TRUE : Boolean.FALSE;
        // Enabled comparison between any type supported by Jeks
        else if (binaryOperatorKey.equals (JeksExpressionSyntax.OPERATOR_DIFFERENT))
          return param1 != null && param1.equals (param2) ? Boolean.FALSE : Boolean.TRUE;
        else
          return super.getBinaryOperatorValue (binaryOperatorKey, param1, param2);
      }
    };

    parser = new ExpressionParser(new JeksExpressionSyntax(), null);
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of tools out there to evaluate expressions; the correct answer will depend on your exact goals.

Two things that I'd look at:

- [Commons EL](http://commons.apache.org/el/), which evaluates [JSP 2.0 expression language](http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/syntax/2.0/syntaxref207.html).
- [Rhino](http://www.mozilla.org/rhino/), which evaluates JavaScript (I think this is part of JDK 1.6, but haven't used it as such).