# Java - Dynamic Comparison with Primitive Data Types

Tags: java, dynamic, operators, conditional-statements, primitive

Friends,

We are writing a framework for a validation...

We do have a config file like below...

```
<root>
<property name="Premium">
    <xmlTag>//Message/Request/Product/Benefit/Premium/amount</xmlTag>
    <valueType>float</valueType>
    <validation condition=">" value="0">Premium Amount cannot be less than Zero.</validation>
</property>
```

I get the XML Value using XPath and convert it to float by `<valueType>` element value...

No, I do have `value="0"` also been converted to float.

Now, I do have to apply the condition which has been specified as `condition=">"`.

I don't want to do this on IF ELSEIF....ELSE loop.

Is there any other way to convert "<" in to an operator `<` or use compare operator on a String?

In this way, my code will be simple and useful for future more operators.

=============================================================================

Thanks all for the suggestions and answers...

I have decided to use the [BeanShell](http://www.beanshell.org/download.html)'s bsh.Interpreter. It does the work for me...

sample code for you all...

```
        System.out.println(new bsh.Interpreter().eval("1 < 0"));
        System.out.println(new bsh.Interpreter().eval("1 > 0"));
        System.out.println(new bsh.Interpreter().eval("1 >= 0"));
        System.out.println(new bsh.Interpreter().eval("0 >= 0"));
        System.out.println(new bsh.Interpreter().eval("1 != 0"));
        System.out.println(new bsh.Interpreter().eval("0 != 0"));
        System.out.println(new bsh.Interpreter().eval("1 == 0"));
        System.out.println(new bsh.Interpreter().eval("0 == 0"));
```

returned me true/false.

Thanks & Good luck...

Comment: You don't have to use `if-then-else` chain, you can use a hash map. But there is no shortcuts to do it dynamically, so you are in for a lot of coding.

Comment: Do you need '<=' as well? (Or any other more-than-one-char operators)

Comment: Have a look at this question as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1432245/java-parse-a-mathematical-expression-given-as-a-string-and-return-a-number and also this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3832323/java-string-and-mathematical-expression-evaluators

Comment: Yes, I would like to cover all comparisons possible like <, <=, >, >=, ==, !=...etc

Comment: Thanks all for the quick reply and many possible ways....

Thanks Angelo for suggesting nice framework...

`System.out.println(new bsh.Interpreter().eval("1 < 0"));
System.out.println(new bsh.Interpreter().eval("1 > 0"));
System.out.println(new bsh.Interpreter().eval("1 >= 0"));
System.out.println(new bsh.Interpreter().eval("0 >= 0"));
System.out.println(new bsh.Interpreter().eval("1 != 0"));
System.out.println(new bsh.Interpreter().eval("0 == 0"));`

[BeanShell's](http://www.beanshell.org/download.html) bsh.Interpreter did the magic

Answer (score 2):

You can use a switch statement

```
char operator = ...;
switch(operator) {
   case '<': return value1 < value2;
   case '=': return value1 == value2;
}
```

Comment: You introduced an assignment in the last `case` by mistake; use `==` instead.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using an expression language such as **Java EL** or even better **Apache Commons Jexl**, since it is much easier to integrate. Here is a code sample taken from [**JEXL** website](http://commons.apache.org/jexl/):

```
    // Assuming we have a JexlEngine instance initialized in our class named 'jexl':
    // Create an expression object for our calculation
    String calculateTax = "((G1 + G2 + G3) * 0.1) + G4";
    Expression e = jexl.createExpression( calculateTax );

    // populate the context
    JexlContext context = new MapContext();
    context.set("G1", businessObject.getTotalSales());
    context.set("G2", taxManager.getTaxCredit(businessObject.getYear()));
    context.set("G3", businessObject.getIntercompanyPayments());
    context.set("G4", -taxManager.getAllowances());
    // ...

    // work it out
    Float result = (Float)e.evaluate(context);
```

In your particular example you could change your validation XML to something like:

```
<property name="Premium">
    <xmlTag>//Message/Request/Product/Benefit/Premium/amount</xmlTag>
    <valueType>float</valueType>
    <validation expression="Premium> 0">Premium Amount cannot be less than Zero.</validation>
</property>
```

and then build up your own JEXL context:

```
JexlContext context = new MapContext();
context.set("PREMIUM", <Premium value fetched from XML>);
```

In my opinion this is the most scalable solution as it allows you to build complex validation expressions in just one line of code.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the primitive value into the corresponding wrapper:

```
Float f = new Float(floatValue)
```

Then you can use the provided `compareTo()` method polymorphically.

EDIT:
You can also have a look at full-featured implementations for expression parsing; besides others that have already been mentioned here, I would add [Spring EL](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.1.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html#expressions-evaluation).

Comment: how does this give the OP the possibility to use the String "<" as comparison method?

Comment: the `<` test should translate into `a.compareTo(b) < 0`. The String `compareTo` will perform the lexicographic test, while the numeric wrappers will do what you expect; however, you can treat them all as `Comparable` instances.

Comment: Note also that all the <, <=, >, >=, ==, != operators can be represented by a table of results for `compareTo()` being < 0, ==0, or >= (so, for example, <= would just be defined as `true, true, false` and != as `true, false, true`)

Comment: I fail to realize how that solves the ops problem of having too many IF-ELSE-ELSEIF hops for every operator.

Comment: Sorry, I think I misunderstood your question. You read the String "<" from the XML and want to use it as such in your code. That's not an option in Java. Also, in my opinion, even in languages that provide an `eval()` procedure you should avoid this.

Comment: To fully answer your question, you should keep a Map that associates each comparison "symbol" (`<`, `<=` etc.) with the corresponding implementation of some `Comparison` interface. Then you can do `comparisons.get("<=").check(a, b)`. Inside the `check()` method you can use `Comparable.compareTo` or some Comparator of yours for custom use cases. You can also use an `Enum` for this if you don't need to add new comparisons without recompiling.

Comment: @DownVoters: shouldn't down-votes be explained somehow ? I want to learn from my mistakes. :)